ACCESS DENIEND showing in content area of Drupal site behind LDAP-PROXY barrier
I'm scratching my head here with an unusual problem which began only AFTER MIGRATION into Drupal 9 / Drupal 10:

try to protect access to site behind proxy-Ldap barrier (so people can access it from outside the institution's facilities, but only if they can successfully respond to a popup windows asking for the user's login credentials inside the institution's network).
once we enter network credentials, the site DOES OPEN, BUT with the "Access Denied" message INSIDE THE CONTENT region;

I thought it could be related to some configuration in the SETTINGS.PHP file, like those of "reverse-proxy" , and I got (from my colleagues in the infrastructure section) a list of internal IPs to use in those settings... but to no effect.
Any clues about this?

I think the technical HTTP implementation of the proxy-LDAP barrier and its integration to Drupal needs explanation for an answer. Drupal’s logs of these events and specific Drupal paths being accessed will be additionally useful in forming an answer. Finally a technical explanation of the migration will prove useful.

Thanks, @monalisa! I have little clue on those, because our teams are not so much integrated. Fellows on the infrastructure team say the proxyLdap process done there are exact the same as for other Drupal 7 sites that we have, which work fine.
This one was not migrated, it started from ground with D10.... and will not accept access.

Got this from one of the blocked accesses to the main content region:
Path: /sites/default/files/js/js_6WAO8O3WuT0jWqqNRVvC8GOHQzP4JgSQI1MDQ65SUyE.js?scope=footer&delta=2&language=pt-br&theme=barrio5_portaldevideos&include=eJx1(...). Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: The used authentication method is not allowed on this route. in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\AuthenticationSubscriber->onExceptionAccessDenied() (line 135 of /var/www/app/drupal/portaldevideos/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/AuthenticationSubscriber.php).
